# Detect when audio is about to end in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I can already check when the audio has ended and then do whatever I want with it. But how can I detect when the audio is just about to end? Let's say only 200 ms is left before the audio ends. I already made a small function to get the current audio's millisecond but can't seem to figure out the logic part. The code is:

```
audio.play();

function detectEnd() {

  var Mins = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60),
      Secs = audio.currentTime - Mins * 60,
      MilliSecs = Math.round(Secs * 1000);

  if( /* the audio is about to end (200 ms remaining) */ ) 
    alert("The audio is about to end...");

}

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', detectEnd, false);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Just looking at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp tells me you should also be using the `audio.duration` property. Though both `duration` and `currentTime` are in seconds, so you'll only be able to check when you're on the last second of the track with these.

Comment: `currentTime` should include milliseconds as fractions of a second, e.g. "23.404". However, "[t]o offer protection against timing attacks and fingerprinting, the precision of [currentTime] might get rounded depending on browser settings.
In Firefox, the privacy.reduceTimerPrecision  preference is enabled by default and defaults to 20us in Firefox 59; in 60 it will be 2ms." --[Reduced time precision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime#Reduced_time_precision)

Comment: So it seems you could use `duration - currentTime <= 0.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible!

```
audio.play();

var count = 0;

function detectEnd() {
  if (audio.duration - audio.currentTime <= 0.2) {
    if (!count) {
      alert("The audio is about to end...");
    } else {}
    count++;
  }
}

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', detectEnd, false);

audio.onended = function() {
  count = 0; // RESET
};
```

PS: I've added a variable `count` to show alert once.

REF URL: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_event_timeupdate

Comment: Most use cases would also need to reset `count` on a `seeked` and/or `pause` listener for replays.

Comment: Glad that it helped you. ~_~

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so:
You already have the `audio.currentTime` , now you need a variable for the total length of the audio with `audio.duration` .
Then, if audio.currentTime == (audio.duration - x) trigger the event.

In this example `x` stands for the remaining time you wish. Note that `audio.duration` is measured in seconds.

Hope it helps